# Retrieve all CSS classes loaded in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, subdomain

**Is it possible to retrieve all the css classes loaded in a document?**

**I don't mean all the css classes that are applied to the elements** but everything received from all CSS files (they might come fron different subdomains)

Example:

Let's say that i have:

/css/style.css (same subdomain as my website)

and

http://different.subdomain/css/morestyles.css

The browser will load the second without any problem.

**How can i get all the classes from the second css file using javascript?**

Comment: I think you can't. Javascript can find applied styles on elements, but I think there is no 'global list of loaded styles'. A possibility would be to get the contents of the CSS file using AJAX, if the file is on the same domain. Then parse the file yourself, but before you do that, maybe you should wonder again *why* you need this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

Comment: Thank you GolezTrol the thing is that the css is on a different subdomain :(

Answer (score 0):

Sure (if I understood you correctly)! Maybe something like:

```
function classes(){
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
var i = 0;
var c = new Array();

while(i < tags.length){
if(c.valueOf(tags[i].className) < 0){
array_push(tags[i].className);
}

return c;
}
```

If you want to get the style information from those classes you could request the CSS file with ajax and use regex to find the classes.

Comment: This is good to parse all styles applied to the dom elements i think. And the idea of getting it through ajax is good as well but it won't work if the css file is on a different subdomain :(

Comment: There is a workaround: You can request a PHP file with ajax, that reads that remote CSS file and echos that. Take a look at this: http://jelaniharris.com/2010/how-to-read-remote-files-using-php/.